# Challenge to SELECT only new records that were added since the last SELECT

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-server-2019, change-tracking

Sometime ago I ran across a question/problem that I misunderstood as the user was not very skilled and I went ahead and solved it in the most ugly, cthullu, chaotic way possible. Now, if this is not the right place to share an interesting exercise in creativity, I apologize.

The problem is:

When running statement **select * from temp1** return only those rows that were added since the last **select** statement was ran. No `WHERE` condition/joins etc. only **select * from temp1**

DDL:

```
create table temp1 (
  id int identity primary key, 
  Location varchar(4), 
  SupplierId tinyint
)
```

**HERE YOU DO WHAT YOU NEED TO DO TO SOLVE THE CHALLENGE **

What should be run after **(NO DELETES, UPDATES OR DDL STATEMENTS)**:

```
insert into temp1 select 'ABCD', 4
insert into temp1 select 'DEFG', 5
select * from temp1
```

returns

1, 'ABCD', 4

2, 'DEFG', 5

then run

```
insert into temp1 select 'TRYE', 7

select * from temp1
```

returns only 3, 'TRYE', 7

Good luck, and may god have mercy on your soul if you ever do something similar in any other fashion than for fun :D

Comment: I'd say you're going to have to use `TIMESTAMP`s (or `DATETIME`s - whatever SQL Server uses) and transactions!

Comment: Vladislav, you should post the solution as an answer and not as an edit to the question.

Comment: Please avoid meta tags like "exercise" etc. Instead, use tags to describe what the problem is about. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I have deleted my first answer (see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=e8e32ce66ddccb2b66e48e0422016b5e)) 'cos it got me a -1 from some shpxre(*)! Anyway, try, try, try again!...

You appear to want "something for nothing" in that you want the system to do what is not normally possible via the "normal" RDBMS's, but you want this to be automatic. Unless there is a seismic shift in the relational paradigm and the approach taken by those who produce relational databases, the functionality you want is going to remain unavailable!

However, there is one workaround that (partially) works that I can think of that you could use (see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=2adec506098faa522ed4841b885dcc2d)).

```
CREATE TABLE temp2
(
  id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
  location VARCHAR (4) NOT NULL, 
  supplier_id TINYINT NOT NULL,
  trans_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

);
```

Populate it (reasons for putting `INSERT`s in a transaction will be discussed below):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO temp2 (location, supplier_id, trans_id) 
  SELECT 'ABCD', 4, CURRENT_TRANSACTION_ID ();
INSERT INTO temp2 (location, supplier_id, trans_id) 
  SELECT 'DEFG', 5, CURRENT_TRANSACTION_ID ();
COMMIT;
```

Check:

```
SELECT * FROM temp2;
```

Result:

```
id  location    supplier_id trans_id    trans_time
 1      ABCD              4 47235270    2021-01-04 20:20:23.737
 2      DEFG              5 47235270    2021-01-04 20:20:23.737
```

So, now for my version of the solution to your particular requirements (maybe you'd like to tell us **why**, exactly, you want to do this?):

We create a **second** table `temp2_to_permanent` thus:

```
CREATE TABLE temp2_to_permanent
(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  location varchar(4) NOT NULL, 
  supplier_id tinyint NOT NULL,
  trans_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  trans_time DATETIME
);
```

Now, we add another record to `temp2`:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO temp2_to_permanent SELECT * FROM temp2;
DELETE FROM temp2;
INSERT INTO temp2  (location, supplier_id, trans_id) 
  SELECT 'TRYE', 7, CURRENT_TRANSACTION_ID();
COMMIT;
```

The more eagle-eyed among you will have noted that I've done a tiny bit more than just `INSERT`ing a record - what I've done is:

- `INSERT`ed the contents of `temp2` into `temp2_to_permanent`
- `DELETED` all records from `temp2` - note, not `TRUNCATE` as this will fail - you can't have DDL within a transaction in SQL Server apparently
- `INSERT`ed the new record into `temp2`

Then, we issue a second

```
SELECT * FROM temp2;
```

Result:

```
id  location    supplier_id trans_id    trans_time
 3      TRYE              7 47238800    2021-01-04 20:30:52.513
```

Now, all of this can be wrapped in a `TRIGGER` (not a SQL Server man - I leave this up to the reader).

There is **one *caveat*** however, if other users are `INSERT`ing at or around the same time, then their records could become interleaved with yours - i.e. they could have also `INSERT`ed a different record during the time between `COMMIT`ing the `INSERT` and `SELECT`ing from the table - `Ye cannae beet the laws o' physics, Jim!"`.

(*) run shpxre through this [site](https://rot13.com/).

Comment: its written in the name and first paragraph. this is a challange/brain tease. not something i want to do. Actually i solved it, and its horrible. this is a challange to see how 'outside the box' you can think :D

Comment: @VladislavZalesak OK - what did **you** do? BTW, what does "cthullu" mean? BTW, as far as I'm concerned, puzzles/challenges are **great**!

Comment: i will post solution in a day or two. Cthullu is a reference to Call to Cthullu, i used it in the meaning that just seeing it threatens your sanity

Comment: @Vérace You can think of *Cthullu* synonymous with the *flying spaghetti monster* in this context which is pretty fitting since it sounds like OP has a very roundabout solution. As far as how outside the box OP is looking for, I could easily even just answer with developing my own RDBMS where `SELECT *` always returns only the records since the last `SELECT`.

Comment: @J.D. - well, it's certainly a different versioning - instead of `SELECT .... AT` (or whatever your temporal query syntax is, you could have a `SELECT ... FROM` - not sure how useful that is - see my point about (near) simultaneous `INSERT`s by other users.

Answer (score 0):

[Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server) is specifically designed for this. It adds further tables to the DB, and other meta-data items.  The  consumer has to track what changes it has seen up to.

I'm using it in my current project to pull changes from the OLTP system into the data warehouse.

Comment: Wouldnt CDC require you to add some kind of where condition to the select statement?

Comment: I've never used CDC, but from what I could research since you've posted your answer, it should track only the changes that occurred to a table and a `SELECT` doesn't cause any change, so how would you know when the last `SELECT` was issued (not last INSERT - which I believe would be captured by CDC) only using CDC? Could you exemplify it, please?

Answer (score 0):

Without the ability to modify the table, or using a `WHERE` clause to query it, then you don't have many options other than using one of the features of SQL Server that are applicable for revision control:

1. [**Change Data Capture (CDC)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) - Change data capture records insert, update, and delete activity that applies to a SQL Server table. This makes the details of the changes available in an easily consumed relational format
2. [**Temporal Tables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables) - A system-versioned temporal table is a type of user table designed to keep a full history of data changes to allow easy point in time analysis.
3. [**DML Triggers**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks-for-dml-triggers) - DML Triggers are used to capture and respond to data changes of a table and can be used to log those changes in another table. You also can `SELECT` those changes triggered on `INSERT` to automatically return the newest change of the table to the client.

Comment: I think you've missed the select that comes right under the first two inserts.

Comment: @Ronaldo Ah yea thanks. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: i am afraid all three of your approaches would require more then select * from temp1 to work

Comment: @VladislavZalesak Can you please clarify your requirements then? Because what you request is not possible **if the only** thing you can do is `SELECT * FROM temp1`.

Comment: @J.D. Running the two inserts, select, then insert, then select only always let select return the rows added since last select.
And it is possible, i tried it before posting it here. But its cthullu as hell.

Comment: @VladislavZalesak but if you can make no other changes to the database, as you've seemed to indicate in your last response, and you can't query the `temp1` table any other way, then it is not possible. I guarantee whatever solution you came up with either does modify the database in some way or doesn't fully solve the problem like you think it does. Please update your post to **fully** clarify your requirements in what can and/or can't be done to the database. E.g. I can write C# code & host it as a CLR function on SQL Server to help solve this problem, but again your requirements are unclear.

Comment: The no modification applies after you star inserting/selecting data. Between create table and first insert, you can do whatever you want

Comment: @VladislavZalesak If that's so, then the 3rd option above with Trigger(s) should be possible to achieve your request. After initial creation of the trigger(s) (which can be done before any data is inserted), the logic is applied automatically. Additionally, CLR can also solve this problem (though a very roundabout approach as well). I'll update my answer when I get a chance to include CLR.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the only thing that can filter silently the output of a select done on a flat table is Row level Security:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver15

The challenge is to capture the IDs already selected. Maybe with a security audit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15 you can caputere selected id and the update the security function applyed by the row level security.

Answer (score 0):

Tadaa, and may i be forgiven :D

```
create table alreadyReturned(id int primary key)
 
create or alter function fn_a (@id int)
returns int
as
begin
    declare @sql varchar(4000),
            @cmd varchar(4000),
            @retval tinyint
    
 
    if not exists (select 1 from alreadyReturned where id = @id)
    begin
        select @sql = 'insert into alreadyReturned select ' + cast(@id as varchar)
        select @cmd = 'sqlcmd -S ' +@@SERVERNAME+ ' -d ' +db_name()+ ' -Q "' + @sql +'"'
        exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd, 'no_output'
        set @retval = 1
    end
    else set @retval = 0
    
return @retval
end 
go
 
CREATE or alter FUNCTION fn_b(@id AS int)  
    RETURNS TABLE   
    RETURN SELECT 1 AS 'SecureCourierShipments'  where  dbo.fn_a(@id) = 1
go
 
 
CREATE SECURITY POLICY bazmek  
 
ADD FILTER PREDICATE dbo.fn_b(id)   
ON dbo.temp1  
WITH (STATE = ON, Schemabinding = off);
```

Comment: This is Row level security :-)

Comment: Yes, but common, that was just half of it :) and the more sane part :)

Comment: Part of this is implicitly equivalent to using a `WHERE` clause, but more so if you're executing commands with `xp_cmdshell` then your solution is on par with my suggestion of using CLR.